# How to not lose '0' digits when using NSDateComponents.(iphone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using Date Formatter, getting the NSDateComponents. And then extracting the individual time components such as hour, minute..etc..
How can I extract these components as NSIntegers without losing the '0' digits at the front of the number.

E.g is today was january 1 2010 5:05, it would print 1-1-2010-5:5
I want 01-01-2010-05:05

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I mean why do you want to print it using the date components and not a date formatter?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way you can keep `0` in the `NSInteger`. As such you can pick one of the approaches here –

**Avoid date components and reprint date in a different format using `NSDateFormatter`**

```
NSCalendar * gregorianCalendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d yyyy H:mm"];
NSDate * theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"January 1 2010 5:05"];

/* Using NSDateFormatter to get the desired format */
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:theDate]);
```

**From Date components**

```
NSInteger flags = (NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit);
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [gregorianCalendar components:flags
                                                         fromDate:theDate];

NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];

NSLog(@"%02ld-%02ld-%ld %02ld:%02ld", day, month, year, hour, minute);
```

**Using NSNumberFormatter** (extending the previous block)

```
NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
[numberFormatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:2];

NSString * hourString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:hour]];
NSString * minuteString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:minute]];
NSString * yearString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:year]];
NSString * monthString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:month]];
NSString * dayString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:day]];

NSLog(@"%@-%@-%@ %@:%@", dayString, monthString, yearString, hourString, minuteString);
```

Comment: the only thing is, this is assuming that certain date components are less than 10, they can be any value.  I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution

Comment: Not really, it is assuming that date components are two digits. If a single digit value is encountered, pad it with 0 so that two digits are printed. There are three different solutions with third dependant on the second.